# How to avoid catching generic exceptions

Tags: c#, exception

In my processing I would like to log any error along with the user and code details and proceed on with my work.

I am currently using a try catch block which includes a generic catch, but is catching a generic exception is a bad thing? Such as the exception could be a stackoverflowexception or outofmemoryexception and need to be handled differently.. .

But I am not sure how to avoid catching these fatal exceptions. I am looking for suggestions.

##### Why I want to catch all exceptions

Because I don't want a failure in one form's processing to affect the others in the loop.

##### Why I am catching specific exceptions:

I understand I can look for stackoverflowexception, outofmemoryexception etc... but my point is, there could be many of them...looking for each and every would make my code lengthy. I am not sure if that is the best process.

Comment: You should know why you would want to catch possible thrown exceptions, otherwise, why to catch them anyway?

Comment: I am catching these exceptions just to log the fact that the form failed...So that I can take corrective actions later. But I just don;t want to halt the entire loop just for this one form/user.

Answer (score 6):

> But I am not sure how to avoid catching these fatal exceptions

Well, 2 things.

First, you can always rethrow them, for example, after logging.

Second, you can catch every exception you want and if you do not catch System.Exception then all you do not catch will bubble up - that is C# 101 for beginners, so if you have a problem with that, back to reading the documentation about exceptions in general.

Comment: I understand that all uncatched exceptions will bubble up. But It means that it will halt my looping process.I don't want a failure in one form processing to affect the others. Hope you are getting my issue.

Comment: Well, what do you do in a out of memory exception? There are a ton of issues that you do not plan for. Basics good programming: FAIL FAST - and then debug the log and fix the bug.

Comment: Thats exactly is my question, I want to fail if it is a fatal/generic exception like outofmemory, as it will affect all  the forms/users. But if it is specific to this form, then I would like to simply log the issue and continue to with other.

Comment: Catch all you can expect and let the rest fall through.

Comment: The form processing involves calling multiple functions/components some of them from third party as well...calling all expected exceptions would make the code really lengthy.

Answer (score 4):

Exceptions cascade down. If you want to handle certain exceptions differently, implement a different catch block.

```
try
{
    ThisMethodMayThrowException();
}
catch(StackOverflowException ex)
{
    //handle a StackOverFlowException
}
catch(OutOfMemoryException ex)
{
    //handle a OutOfMemoryException 
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //handle all other types.
}
```

In general though, you should only plan to handle expected exceptions. For example, if you're writing to a file that you expect to exist, you might anticipate a `FileNotFoundException`. If you tried to handle every possible exception, your code would become quite long and unwieldy, to little benefit.

Microsoft provides excellent info on [exception handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173162.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Reverse your thinking... because the advice `catching generic exception` is being misinterpreted.

Handle all exceptions **which are known explicitly** (do the log and continue processing), but *always have a generic catch all exception handler* to **stop** all processing and handle that unknown.

In your example an overflow exception could comprise data or let malicious actors take over the system in unexpected ways; hence continuing on, should not be done.

Answer (score 0):

> I am currently using a try catch block which includes a generic catch,
>   but I have heard from many people that catching generic exception is a
>   bad thing(as the exception could be a stackoverflowexception or
>   outofmemoryexception).

You should know which `Exception` types your method calls ***might*** throw.

It could be discovered either at the Method documentation, example:

```
 /// <exception cref="DivideByZeroException">Why it's thrown.</exception>
 public void MethodThatMightThrowDivideByZeroException(){...}
```

or by looking at the Method code, example:

```
throw new DivideByZeroException();
```

**That way, you would be able to catch it easily:**

```
try
{
    ThisMethodMayThrowException();
}
catch(DivideByZeroException ex)
{
    //handle a DivideByZeroException 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know all the exceptions you want to catch, you write a catch block for each specifically:

```
try
{
}
catch (IOException)
{
}
catch (InvalidCastException)
{
}
...
```

Then all the ones you don't want to catch (and thus allow to potentially take down your program) will keep bubbling up.